# Smart Contract Testing of Crowd Funding

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat, ethereumjs, testing

Hi Iam new in solidity program i don't know how to test the donate function can anybody help me how to test?
Actually I want to test when some donate the donater balance is minus and the person who created a campaign his balance is increase when someone donate.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

pragma solidity >0.7.0 <=0.9.0;

contract CampaignFactory {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;

    event campaignCreated(
        string title,
        uint requiredAmount,
        address indexed owner,
        address campaignAddress,
        string imgURI,
        uint indexed timestamp,
        string indexed category
    );

    function createCampaign(
        string memory campaignTitle, 
        uint requiredCampaignAmount, 
        string memory imgURI, 
        string memory category,
        string memory storyURI) public
    {

        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(
            campaignTitle, requiredCampaignAmount, imgURI, storyURI, msg.sender);
        

        deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCampaign));

        emit campaignCreated(
            campaignTitle, 
            requiredCampaignAmount, 
            msg.sender, 
            address(newCampaign),
            imgURI,
            block.timestamp,
            category
        );

    }
}


contract Campaign {
    string public title;
    uint public requiredAmount;
    string public image;
    string public story;
    address payable public owner;
    uint public receivedAmount;

    event donated(address indexed donar, uint indexed amount, uint indexed timestamp);

    constructor(
        string memory campaignTitle, 
        uint requiredCampaignAmount, 
        string memory imgURI,
        string memory storyURI,
        address campaignOwner
    ) {
        title = campaignTitle;
        requiredAmount = requiredCampaignAmount;
        image = imgURI;
        story = storyURI;
        owner = payable(campaignOwner);
    }
```

Here is donate function

```
    function donate() public payable {
        require(requiredAmount > receivedAmount, "required amount fullfilled");
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
        receivedAmount += msg.value;
        emit donated(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Foundry (recommended) or Hardhat for testing.

This is a good course by @patrick-collins which goes in depth https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umepbfKp5rI&t=278s

Recommended to read:
https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/checks_effects_interactions.html

Here's an outline of a test in Hardhat

```
// 1. Import necessary modules and libraries

describe("Campaign", function () {
  let campaign;
  let owner;

  // 2. Define beforeEach hook to deploy a fresh instance of the contract

  beforeEach(async function () {
    // a. Deploy the contract using the Contract Factory
    // b. Get the owner's signer
  });

  // 3. Write the test case for the donate function

  it("should update received amount and decrease contract balance when donating", async function () {
    // a. Get the initial balance of the owner
    // b. Define the donation amount

    // c. Call the donate function with the donation amount

    // d. Assert that the received amount is updated correctly
    // e. Assert that the contract balance of the owner has decreased by the donation amount
  });
});
```